# Getting Team Foundation to recognize new files added to source controlled directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I am working on a PHP project, so I am not using Visual Studio, however the company I work at is mostly a .NET shop so we use Team Foundation Server for version control. I can use VS to manually add files to the TFS project but that is a bit cumbersome when I am adding a bunch of new files, I pretty much have to add the file right after I create it so I don't forget.

What I want to know is if there is a way to have TFS pick up a new file added to a directory that is under source control for a project. For instance if I added a few PHP files to the source controlled html directory I would like to be able to just go to check in pending changes in TFS and have the newly added files included in the list. Does anyone know if this is possible? Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to have this happen automatically with TFS 2010 or below. I've seen a video that says they'll be adding this feature for the next release.

In the meantime, you can use Source Control Explorer, then right-click a folder in the left pane and choose "Add Items to Folder". Follow the dialog and you'll be able to add any of the items that haven't previously been added.

Comment: You could also install the [TFS 2010 power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f) and use the Windows Explorer integration. You still need to have Team Explorer installed but you can do most version control operations from the context menu which saves having Visual Studio open.